# Write to a file from another file and delete line from file

Tags: python, file

My file(outputfile6.txt) is:

```
1രാമന്‍ 2സീതയെ 3കണ്ടു 4.
5അവന്‍ 6അവള്‍ക്ക് 7പൂവ്‌ 8കൊടുത്തു 9.
10അവള്‍ 11അത്‌ 12വാങ്ങി 13.
14അവര്‍ 15ഒരുമിച്ച്‌ 16കോട്ടയത്ത്‌ 17പോയി 18.
19അവിടെ 20വെച്ച്‌ 21അവര്‍ക്ക്‌ 22പരീക്ഷ 23ഉണ്ട് 24ആയിരുന്നു 25. 
26അവിടെ 27വെച്ച്‌ 28രാമന്‍ 29ലക്ഷ്മനനെ 30കണ്ടു 31.
32അവന്‍ 33രാമനോടു 34സംസാരിച്ചു 35.
36ലക്ഷ്മണന്‍ 37സീതയെ 38കണ്ടു 39.
40അവനെ 41അവള്‍ക്ക്‌ 42ഇഷ്ടമായി 43.
44ഈ 45വഴ 46ആണ് 47അവര്‍ 48പണ്ട് 49നടന്നത്‌ 50.
```

Is it possible to write these lines to another file on the basis of line number?
For eg:
 print from line no: 1 to 5. After that i want to delete those lines written to another file. This should be continued until EOF.
Since the above concept is a part of my code, I can't reveal my whole code.
For my work. First i found my starting sentence. and then found the final sentence i want.

```
fp = codecs.open('outputfile6.txt', encoding='utf-8')
lines1 = fp.readlines()
fp.close()
fb = codecs.open('outputfile7.txt', 'w')
write=0
for l in lines1:
    if i in l:#i is my search item which contains in the starting sentence.
        write=1
    if write==1:
        fb.write(l.encode('UTF-8'))
    if line_upto in l:#line_upto is a string which contains in the lastsentence
        write=0
        break
fb.close()#Here i didn't get a code for deleting lines from the file.
```

My output is:
I always get outputfile7.txt same as outputfile6.txt
My expected outputfile7.txt is:

```
1രാമന്‍ 2സീതയെ 3കണ്ടു 4.  
5അവന്‍ 6അവള്‍ക്ക് 7പൂവ്‌ 8കൊടുത്തു 9.  
10അവള്‍ 11അത്‌ 12വാങ്ങി 13.  
14അവര്‍ 15ഒരുമിച്ച്‌ 16കോട്ടയത്ത്‌ 17പോയി 18.    
19അവിടെ 20വെച്ച്‌ 21അവര്‍ക്ക്‌ 22പരീക്ഷ 23ഉണ്ട് 24ആയിരുന്നു 25.
```

Comment: what is '\\'? In python we use '#' for comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code for deleting lines:

here end is the line number upto which i want to delete from the file.

```
fp = codecs.open('outputfile6.txt', encoding='utf-8')
lines1 = fp.readlines()
fp.close()
fb = codecs.open('outputfile6.txt', 'w')
for j in range(0,len(lines1)):
    if j>end:
        fb.write(lines1[j].encode('UTF-8'))

fb.close()
```

If properly attach this code to above code,expected output will be obtained.